# Find any sequence in fractional part of $e^x$?

Tags: exponentiation, fractional-part

For any infinite sequence of digits $s$, does an integer number $x$ always exist, such that the fractional part of the solution for $e^x = s$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, by cardinality reasons. There are uncountably many such sequences, but only countably many integers.

Comment: Though if you relax the requirement that $x$ be an integer and allow it to be any real, then of course the answer is yes (which is what I mistakenly thought the question was until you gave your answer and saved me a bit of embarrassment, so +1 for that).